# How to save a HTMLElement (Table) in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I've been trying this for a while now and could not find anything online...

I have a project, where tablerows get added to a table. Works fine.

Now I want to save the Table in the localStorage, so I can load it again. (overwrite the existing table).

```
 function saveProject(){
                //TODO: Implement Save functionality
            var projects = [];
            projects.push($('#tubes table')[0].innerHTML);
            localStorage.setItem('projects', projects);
          //console.log(localStorage.getItem('projects'));
```

The problem is the Array "projects" has (after one save) 2000+ elements. But all I want is the whole table to be saved to the first (or appending later) index.

In the end I want the different Saves to be listed on a Option element:

```
    function loadSaveStates(){
     alert('loading saved states...');
     var projects = localStorage.getItem('projects');
     select = document.getElementById('selectSave'); //my Dropdown
     var length = projects.length,
         element = null;
     console.log(length);

     for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        element = projects[i];
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = i;
        opt.innerHTML = 'project ' + i;
        select.appendChild(opt);

    } 
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coose to stay with localStorage, but insted of using an Array I just let the user give every project a name and create a new Item for every Save:

```
    function saveProject(){
   //TODO: Implement Save functionality
            var pname=prompt("Please enter your project name:","projectname")
            var text = $('#mainTable')[0].innerHTML;
            //console.log(text);
            localStorage.setItem(pname, text);
            //console.log(localStorage.key(2));
            loadSaveStates();
        }

function loadProject(){
    var selected = $('#selectSave')[0].selectedIndex
    //console.log(selected);
    if (localStorage.key(selected) == 'jStorage'){
            selected++;
    }
        var innerHTMLTable = localStorage[localStorage.key(selected)];
        //console.log(innerHTMLTable);
        $('#mainTable')[0].innerHTML = innerHTMLTable;

    updateHandlers();
}

function deleteProject(){
    var selected = $('#selectSave')[0].selectedIndex
    var pname = $('#selectSave')[0].options[selected].value

    $('#selectSave')[0].remove(selected);
    localStorage.removeItem(pname);

    //console.log(pname);
    loadSaveStates();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by `jquery`, are you interested in this, if yes.. then try following code

For setting the value

```
$.jStorage.set("projects", $.trim(projects));
```

For Getting the data

```
$.jStorage.get("projects");
```

For deleting the data with key

```
$.jStorage.deleteKey("projects");
```

Comment: The problem is I want to be able to store multiple projects. Thats why I tried using an Array.

Comment: so first make a array of projects and then save that array in the storage.